# Oracle add layer and Oracle Connection icons are missing

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial, odbc, red-hat

I have recently installed QGIS 2.8 and Oracle 11.2 Client on Linux Red Hat 7.

Everything was fine, I am able to access Oracle database, as well as running QGIS. 
Unlike QGIS 2.8 from WIndows, Linux version does not have Add Oracle spatial layers and Oracle new connection icons.

I think the Oracle support was removed by QGIS. Is this correct?

The machine where QGIS runs has installed Oracle Client 11g, unixODBC and SQL Developer.

I have tested the oracle connectivity from a terminal windows as well as from SQL Developer and it works.

I tried as alternative to load spatial data the followings:

- cx_Oracle module from python: it connects to oracle from QGIS python console but cx_Oracle does not have functions to add SDO date to a QGIS layer.
- Add vector layer from Database ODBC- does not connect to an Oracle

Comment: can you use the command line 'commander' and call up oracle_spatial? http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing/commander.html

Comment: I realize this is a rather old thread, but did you find a solution to your problem in Linux?